# How can I retrieve "data" from jQuery Ajax on server side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

How can I retrieve the 'data' which is sent from a client? (in field 'data')

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnAddProductAjax').click(function () {
            var name = $('#txtProductName').val();
            var units = $('#txtUnitsInStock').val();
            var price = $('#txtPrice').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AddProductAjax", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    productname: name,
                    unitsinstock: units,
                    price: price
                },
                success: function (data) {                        
                    $('#divResult').html(data);
                    alert('Product added successfully');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I use this data

```
data: {
    productname: name,
    unitsinstock: units,
    price: price
 },
```

in my server-side action 'AddProductAjax' ?

```
public JsonResult AddProductAjax(string data)
{
    //retrieve data which is sent from client and do something
    return Json(json_data);
}
```

I tried :

- to get data from Request.QueryString[]
- AddProductAjax(string name, int units, int price)
- AddProductAjax(Product prod)

Googled for hours, no result

UPD:
If I define action like

```
    AddProductAjax(string productname, int unitsinstock, decimal price)
```

- nothing happens. Ajax doesn't even call this action. 
If I try

```
    AddProductAjax(string productname, string unitsinstock, string price)
```

- in debugger all the fields are empty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to specify to MVC what type of request the action should expect using Attributes. Both the `HttpPost` and `HttpGet` attributes are found in `System.Web.Mvc`.

Like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddProductAjax(string productname, int unitsinstock, 
                                 decimal price)
{
    //logic...

    return Json(json_data);
}
```

If it doesn't work at first, there is a chance you'll need to define the parameters (the variables in the parentheses) as `string`s and then parse each one to retrieve the values inside, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddProductAjax(string productname, string unitsinstock, 
                                 string price)
{
    int units = 0;
    int.TryParse(unitsinstock, out units);

    decimal decPrice = 0.00;
    decimal.TryParse(price, out decPrice);

    //logic...

    return Json(json_data);
}
```

Comment: If I define action like AddProductAjax(string productname, int unitsinstock, decimal price) - nothing happens. Ajax doesn't even call this action. If I try AddProductAjax(string productname, string unitsinstock, string price) - in debugger all the fields are empty!

Comment: I found the mistake - I had several textfields with same IDs. Thank you for your answer!